authenticate using ms_identity_web and certificate
I am trying to write my first web app using flask and authenticate against Azure AD. Seems easiest way to do the authentication is ms-identity-web module. I have found this sample and tutorial on web:
ms-identity-python-flask-webapp-authentication
Everything looks good, the only issue that I am having is client_credential. ms-identity-web is expecting a string (client secret) but in my case, I need to use a certificate. I have generated public/private keys and uploaded public key to the azure registered app. I am able to authenticate using the private key with MSAL but cannot find a way to do that using ms-identity-web. In the sample code there is json config file and it has a key named "client_secret". I tried to pass a dictionary as value for that element but it didn't work.  Appreciate any hint on how should I pass private key as client_credential.
"client_credential": {
        "thumbprint": "450504A...",
        "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n...\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
}

I know I can use MSAL or azure.identity or other modules to accomplish this and I know ms-identity-web is just a wrapper around MSAL and azure.identity but I am curious on how can I do it using this specific module.


I know I can use MSAL or azure.identity or other modules to accomplish and I know ms-identity-web is just a wrapper around MSAL and azure.identity but I am curious on how can I do it using this specific module.


One potential solution could involve modifying the module to support client certificate authentication. This might require diving into the source code of the module and understanding how it interacts with MSAL and Azure AD.

Alternatively, we could consider using the MSAL library directly in the Flask app to handle authentication using the client certificate. As You mentioned that you were able to authenticate using MSAL with the private key, so this might be a feasible approach. You can still leverage Flask for your web app and use MSAL for authentication separately.

If you choose to go with MSAL directly, you’ll need to implement the authentication logic in your Flask routes.

Code:
import logging
from flask import Flask, current_app, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_session import Session
from pathlib import Path
import app_config
from ms_identity_web import IdentityWebPython
from ms_identity_web.adapters import FlaskContextAdapter
from ms_identity_web.errors import NotAuthenticatedError
from ms_identity_web.configuration import AADConfig
 
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, root_path=Path(__file__).parent)
    app.config.from_object(app_config)
    Session(app)
    app.register_error_handler(NotAuthenticatedError, lambda err: (render_template('auth/401.html'), err.code))
 
    aad_configuration = AADConfig.parse_json('aad.config.json')
    app.logger.level = logging.INFO
 
    if app.config.get('ENV') == 'production':
        from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
        app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
        aad_configuration.client.client_certificate = {
            "path": "path/to/certificate.pem",
            "thumbprint": "<CERT_THUMBPRINT>"
        }
 
    AADConfig.sanity_check_configs(aad_configuration)
    adapter = FlaskContextAdapter(app)
    ms_identity_web = IdentityWebPython(aad_configuration, adapter)
 
    @app.route('/')
    @app.route('/sign_in_status')
    def index():
        return render_template('auth/status.html')
 
    @app.route('/token_details')
    @ms_identity_web.login_required
    def token_details():
        current_app.logger.info("token_details: user is authenticated, will display token details")
        return render_template('auth/token.html')
 
    return app
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=create_app()
    app.run(ssl_context='adhoc')
 
app=create_app()

config.json :
"client": {  
"client_id": "your_client_id",  
"client_credential": {  
"path": "path/to/certificate.pem",  
"thumbprint": "<CERT_THUMBPRINT>"  
}


Use the msal.ConfidentialClientApplication class from the MSAL library to authenticate using the client certificate.

Redirect:

Sign-in Status:



I went through the module and seems the problem is the module is converting dictionaries to namespace.
parsed_config = json.load(cfg, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))

ms-identity-web is a wrapper around MSAL. It means when it tries to create an object from class msal.ConfidentialClientApplication, it sends a namespace instead of a dictionary as argument. The actual solution is changing the module and prevent the conversion but I would rather not to do that as an update would overwrite the changes. For my scenario, I fixed it with adding below code to my scripts.
    if type(aad_configuration.client.client_credential) != str:
        aad_configuration.client.client_credential = vars(aad_configuration.client.client_credential)

It is not the best solution, as it does not consider all possible options for client_credential but it solves my problem for now.
